# Running multi-container docker with elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerrun.aws.json

I want to deploy an application with multi-container docker in elastic beanstalk. The problem is the EBS dashboard says the service deployed successfully but I am not able to access the application from the browser using the URL shown in the dashboard. Also, I am not able to access different services deployed in different ports.

Following is my Dockerrun.aws.json which is the only file I zipped and uploaded in the EBS selecting the platform as Multi-Container Docker -

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "eureka-server",
      "image": "name/tag-1",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8761,
          "containerPort": 8761
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currency-exchange",
      "image": "name/tag-2",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "eureka-server"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currency-conversion",
      "image": "name/tag-3",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8100,
          "containerPort": 8100
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "eureka-server"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: On a side note, avoid having all containers as essential, this will help you to easily debug by knowing which container did not start thus causing the build failure